# Implementation of Kallmann's Dynamic Constrained Delaunay Triangulation algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, implementation

Does anyone know of any open source implementation (preferably in java) of Kallmann's DCDT algorithm? If there's another DCDT algorithm that has been implemented, that may work as well. I wasn't sure if I should post this here or on StackOverflow, so let me know if this is the wrong place to post.

EDIT: Here's the algorithm: http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/100269/files/Kallmann_and_al_Geometric_Modeling_03.pdf

Comment: Have you asked the authors ? They specifically say to contact the first author for the code.

Comment: Damn i did not see that... well that is very handy!

Answer (score 2):

He keeps the source code on his web page : http://graphics.ucmerced.edu/software/tripath/index.html

Comment: you should mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: It doesn't let me for another couple of hours bc I don't have enough karma